# Is this optimal substructure equation correct?

Tags: dynamic-programming

Given a m x n grid filled with non-negative numbers, find a path from bottom right to top left which minimizes the sum of all numbers along its path.

We start from bottom right corner or (m,n) and our goal is to go to position (1,1) or top left corner.

I am just a little confused and i dont know if i got right the top-down approach 
Is the Optimal Substructure as follows?

`CostToMove(i,j) = Min(CostToMove(i-1,j), CostToMove (i, j+1))  + Cost(i,j)`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the good approach. There is a little problem you need to fix: `CostToMove (i, j+1)`. Here you are going *right* not *left*, so I guess you wanted to say `CostToMove (i, j-1)`

Comment: Alright thanks, and when i will turn the above approach to iterative i should do something like : For(i=n to 1).....For (j=m to 1) right? I mean the for should start from(m,n) and go to (1,1)

Comment: No it's the opposite. Your big task is to find the cost for (m, n), so in the iterative approach it is the last you compute, you start from (1, 1). So it will be `for( i=1 to n).. for (j=1 to m)`

Comment: No above i say "We start from bottom right corner or (m,n) and our goal is to go to position (1,1)" ..if thats the case then we do For(i=n to 1).....For (j=m to 1) ? So i am asking for the case where the task if to find the cost for (1,1)

Comment: In fact you are computing the cost of your decisions. The simplest decision you will make is at `(1, 1)` where basically you will not move. then for example at `(2, 2)` you will decide whether to go up or left depending on the cost in (1, 2) and (2, 1). So they need to be computed before. If you repeat this process iteratively you will find that the last cost you compute is (m, n), the cell from which you start

Comment: Hmm alright i see your point, but both seem to be correct.Anyway i will think it again again.Thanks anyway!!